# installing PYQT4 & SIP on window 10 , python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have problem with installing SIP and PYQT4 on windows 10 64 bit, python 2.7.
I have downloaded the source from riverbank and extrated it, then opened cmd and changed the directory to SIP folder then run

C:\Users\Hema\Desktop\sip-4.19.7>python configure.py

give me attached image that make file created as attached.

[image]

Then when type make or make install give me unrecognized or unknown command. I have read from riverbank and know that need to make build to SIP then do similar process for pyqt4.....any one help me what should i do??

python 2.7.14 --> installed

anaconda 2.7.14--> installed

Comment: You can use the wheel? https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4

Comment: i have used it and installed by pip for windows 32 not 64 bit as it nor run with me ....after installing it not able also to make import to it and not actually installed.....